General Sums of Cardinals
I'm aware of the formula
$\kappa_1 + \kappa_2 = \max\{\kappa_1, \kappa_2\}$ where one of $\kappa_1$ or $\kappa_2$ are infinite ordinals. I've been curious about generalizing this result.
My intuition tells me that if at least one $\kappa_i$ is infinite:
$\displaystyle \sum_{i \in I} \kappa_i = \sup_{i \in I} \kappa_i$
In general, it's easy to generalize the max result to a finite number of additions since you can just perform ordinary induction over the naturals to show it. I'm still learning about transfinite induction and transfinite cardinal arithmetic though and I'm unsure of how I might begin to prove the limit ordinal cases.

That formula is not correct… what if $I$ is uncountable and $\kappa_i=\aleph_0?$ (Or to point out the same thing in your last calculation, what is $\sum_{n<\omega} 1$? It’s not $\sup_{n<\omega} 1$.)

But that’s the only issue. In general the formula is $\sum_i\kappa_i= \max(\sup_i\kappa_i,|{i\in I:\kappa_i>0}|)$, provided one of the two cardinals in the maximum on the RHS is infinite.

Ah my mistake. I was typing this up from intuition. Yes that last formula is not correct as we need one of the cardinals to be infinite. Silly me. Why is there a max after the sup? The sup of a set of cardinals is a single number and unique. Also curious how this would even be proven.

My point was that "we need one of the cardinals to be infinite" is sort of a red herring. Really "we need one of our cardinals to be at least as large as the index set" in order for it to just be the sup (even that's not precisely correct, but it's close). What I wrote was the max of two cardinals. The first cardinal is $\sup_i \kappa_i$ and the second is $|{i\in I: \kappa_i > 0}|$. In the case where all $\kappa_i > 0,$ the second is just $|I|$ and we can write it $\sum_i \kappa_i = \max(\sup_i \kappa_i, |I|).$ You can find a proof in Jech's set theory book, lemma 5.8.

Ah that does make sense. So $\sum_{\alpha < \omega_1} \aleph_0 = \aleph_1$. The supremum in that case is $\aleph_0$, but since we are summing up to $\omega_1$ we get the final sum to be $|\omega_1| = \aleph_1$ That does seem to track. I forget that there's two competing things happening, the sum of large cardinalities and their supremum, and the fact that we are summing uncountably many of them.
